# Openssl Sha1 compile issue

Tags: c++

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned char ibuf[] = "compute sha1";
    unsigned char obuf[20];

    SHA1(ibuf, strlen(ibuf), obuf);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("%02x ", obuf[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


g++ file.cpp -o file -l libssl


file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
file.cpp:29:27: error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/string.h:399:15: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘size_t strlen(const char*)’ [-fpermissive]
```

Wonder whats wrong.. I am trying to compute a sha1

Comment: I didn't try your code, how about remove unsigned from ibuf's declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I wonder if it got lost in anonymization, but it seems to me there's missing

```
include <string.h>
```

and the commandline should really look more like:

```
g++ file.cpp -o file -lssl
```

You're using C++ compiler. C++ compilers are usually very strict about types. You've defined `ibuf` to be `unsigned char` (and used in strlen it is treated as `unsigned char *`)  and `strlen` expects `const char*`, so it produces an error.

You have following options:

1. you can just cast `ibuf` in `strlen`:

   ```
   SHA1(ibuf, strlen((const char *)ibuf), obuf);
   ```
2. you can use suggested `-fpermissive` flag to make `g++` more forgiving and transform errors to mere warnings, although I wouldn't recommend it:

   ```
   g++ -fpermissive file.cpp -o file -lssl
   ```
3. As the code looks just like a plain `C`, maybe you don't need `C++` compiler. If that's the case, just use C-compiler instead of `C++`:

   ```
   gcc file.cpp -o file -lssl
   ```

   You would then need to remove `include <algorithm>` and `namespace..`.

Comment: @user1777711 with which option (1, 2, or 3) ?